# D3 multiseries chart drawing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to draw [multiseries chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) for my custom data

```
client_ip,timestamp,bytes_transfered
92.239.29.77,1412109000000,577818
92.239.29.77,1412110830000,108257
92.239.29.77,1412112600000,20922726
92.239.29.77,1412132430000,3190
92.239.29.78,1412109000000,57818
92.239.29.78,1412110830000,10257
92.239.29.78,1412112600000,2022726
```

i replaced all the variables

> symbol,date,price

with

> client_ip,timestamp,bytes_transfered

also

> var parse = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;       with
>   var parse = d3.time.format("%S %L").parse;

but i dont see the first graph at all now. But i see some weird graphs as well. Kindly let me know how i can fix this.

Comment: Any messages in the console?

Comment: There is no error message, infact i see some of the graphs but the first, second and third are not visible. I see some warnings though but it shows some code only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the structure of the data, it's not the same as the data in the link you posted.  You can use the data in its current structure, but you'll have to do some work.  To me it looks like to want to plot multiple series by the `client ip`, so you'll need to organise your data by `client ip`.  With `d3` this can easily be done with [d3.nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest).  So you use something like:

```
var clients = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.client_ip; })
    .entries(data);
```

This function would yield a nested object organised by `client_ip` with the `timestamp` and `bytes_transfered` organised under `values`.  Which would look, something like:

`{
    "Objectkey": "92.239.29.77",
    "values": [
        {
            "bytes_transfered": "577818",
            "client_ip": "92.239.29.77",
            "timestamp": "WedOct01201406: 30: 00"
        },
        {
            "bytes_transfered": "108257",
            "client_ip": "92.239.29.77",
            "timestamp": "WedOct01201407: 30: 00"
        }
    ]
}`

The next issue was that the `timestamp` variable hasn't been passed correctly.  Your data is in unix time, so all you need to do is pass it to javascripts `new Date` function, as in:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.timestamp = new Date(+d.timestamp);
});
```

You then need to modify the line function, as in:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.bytes_transfered); });
```

And also the domain calls

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp; }));

y.domain([
    d3.min(clients, 
        function(c) { 
            return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { 
                return +v.bytes_transfered; 
            }); 
         }),
    d3.max(clients, 
        function(c) { 
            return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { 
                return +v.bytes_transfered; 
            }); 
         })
]);
```

Also, note the `+` in front of the `v.bytes_transfered`.  This is short hand for passing a string to number in javascript.

And putting it altogether you get [this](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/e927fefcce408ddbbe6d)